# Copy a .bat off a USB and copy it to the Startup folder script - WinXP

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm a Mac/iPhone dev so I don't know very much about Windows scripting...
The point is I have to install a startup app on many computers, so I'd like to have a USB stick with two .bat files:

1. would be the actual "app"
2. would be the script that would copy the 1st.bat off my USB to the Windows startup folder...

How can I do that?

the name of my usb is "USB" and the name of my startup app is "startup.bat".
How I already said, I'm extremely lame in Windows programing, and I need it acutely ;)

Thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following script.  This will cause the application to run whenever the current user logs in.  Without administrative privilages, you won't be able to do it for all users in one go.

```
@Echo Off
CD /D %~dp0
Set StartupFolder=%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
If Exist "%StartupFolder%" Goto :FoundStartup
Set StartupFolder=%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
If Exist "%StartupFolder%" Goto :FoundStartup
Echo Cannot find Startup folder.
Exit /B

:FoundStartup
Copy "MyApp" "%StartupFolder%"
```

Each line does the following:

1. Turn off command echoing, making the script look cleaner to the end user.
2. Set the current directory to wherever this script is located.
3. Set the Startup folder's path as expected in Windows Vista or later.
4. If this folder exists, jump to the copying stage.
5. Set the Startup folder's path as expected in Windows 2000 or later.
6. If this folder exists, jump to the copying stage.
7. Report that the Startup folder can't be found.
8. Exit the batch script.
9. A label that can be jumped to.
10. Copy "MyApp" from the current folder (USB) to the Startup folder.

Comment: the problem is - what if my drive letter isn't D? Thanks a lot... Can't I do it just using "CD USB"? Thx!

Comment: It doesn't use drive letter D:.  It uses the drive letter that the script is located in.  `%~0dp` is code for "this script's drive and path".  If you script is "E:\MyInstaller\Install.bat", then `%~dp0` is "E:\MyInstaller".  `Dir /D` is "change drive and path".

Comment: and what about if my startup app is a .bat? will it work? thx... Cause this doesn't work yet :(

Comment: Are you trying to make this run when you plug the USB stick in or when the user runs your script?  To have the USB drive autoplay, you need to create a [AutoRun.inf](http://autorun.moonvalley.com/autoruninf.htm) file, but this only works from USB drives on Windows XP or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to take credit for Hand-E-Food's answer, but I figured out why his code didn't work and I can't reply to his answer, so here it is.  Instead of using quotes around the `%StartupFolder%` variable in the `Copy` line, use them around the path for `Set StartupFolder`.  Therefore, the code would be as follows.

```
@Echo Off
CD /D %~dp0
Set StartupFolder="%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
If Exist %StartupFolder% Goto :FoundStartup
Set StartupFolder="%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
If Exist %StartupFolder% Goto :FoundStartup
Echo Cannot find Startup folder.
Exit /B

:FoundStartup
Copy "MyApp" %StartupFolder%
```

The only reason I figured this out is because it wasn't doing **anything** for me either, so I tried removing the quotes around `%StartupFolder%` and that resulted in an error message that it couldn't find the folder, but at least I knew it was doing something at the end.  Once I figured out that it was looking for the wrong folder because it thought the folder name stopped at the first space in its name, I simply added in the quotes and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace app.bat with whatever your actual app is called). This should work on Windows 2000 and up.

```
IF EXIST "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\*.*" COPY APP.BAT "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"
IF EXIST "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\*.*" COPY APP.BAT "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

Comment: but where do I tell it where to copy it from?

Comment: or do I put this into my "startup.bat" script?

Comment: Wouldn't those be protected locations on Vista and up?

Comment: If you are double clicking the copying batch file, it will default to the current directory I believe., so you don't need to specify a full path. Security is a concern, but I'm guessing you have permissions to run this on the client.